# print pausing during printing

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-cr-10

I got a new CR-10S 3D printer (I received it at Christmas). It has been printing just fine until yesterday, I was doing a print and it randomly paused, it did not restart on its own, I had to restart the print, then the item finished just fine.  I am printing today, a very small item, the printer now stopped 3 times.  How can I fix this, or do I need to return it?

Comment: Hi Lori, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Printers sometimes stop if the stepper drivers get too hot. Is the cooling of the main board working, have cooling radiators fallen off from the stepper driver chips? Which slicer and version do you use?

Comment: Do note this has been asked multiple times; please look at [this question](/q/10673), and specific questions for the CR-10: [this one](/q/11174) and [this one](/q/10248).

Comment: Sound more like miniumum layer time.

Comment: @Trish Yes it does, but that is already in the answers of the linked question, I merely provided a different view. Another possibility is Cura version 4.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CR-10S Pro pausing and starting again](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11174/cr-10s-pro-pausing-and-starting-again)

Answer (score 2):

The cr10s has a filament run-out sensor. If the microswitch doesn't function properly, or you have issues with the wiring, the print pauses.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can write what the printer says when it stops.

I suggest you try printing other small objects. If that also stops then the printer itself has a problem. But if the printer prints other objects without stopping, then the one you want to print has bad gcode files. You also need to make sure to keep it up-to-date Cura. It would also be great if you can update your printer firmware. But other than that, problems could be heat problem, power problem, and other stuff; it would be great again if you can write the problem that says on the printer as it stops...

Answer (score 0):

Just an off chance: you might somehow have pause instructions being set into the G-code without your being aware.